# WooCommerce customisations break page in PHP 7.2 but not 7.0

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got the following function that modifies the checkout fields in WooCommerce. The code works fine in PHP 7.0 but after upgrading to 7.2 the checkout page just displays a white screen.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

  $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = 'Mobile number';
  $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['label'] = ' ';
  $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['class'] = '';
  $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['class'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']['class'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']['class'] = '';

  return $fields;
}
```

If I comment out some of the `$fields[ ...` lines the page works again, however it seems to be random which ones I comment out to make it work!

First of all: **Why does this upset PHP 7.2?** I'd really like to understand why this breaks the page.

Second: **How can I make this customisation work in PHP 7.2?**

-

*FYI: My testing environment only has the WooCommerce plugin activated and is using the Twenty Seventeen theme*

Comment: Have you set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your wp-config.php file? You should also check your http server error logs ...

Comment: Seems to be [working fine](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ffd92cec1b74be837b837811d77ab3c35b542a7) in 7.2.4 and [7.0.1](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ffd92cec1b74be837b837811d77ab3c35b542a7)